# Are there anyway to disable annotation in spring4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-annotations

I have a question, maybe simple, but I can not find out the solution.

I am using spring boot and added some annotation to the code like this:

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

But in some other environment, for example, in production environment, we want to remove EurekaClient, but I do not want to manually remove it manually for each environment, instead, I want to use environment variable or command line parameter to control the behavior. I suppose to do this way:

```
@EnableEurekaClient(Enabled = {EnableEureka})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class MyApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
        }
}
```

Then I can easily start this application without touching the code.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would want to work with [Spring Boot Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). Split out the `@EnableEurekaClient` to another `@Configuration` class and also add an `@Profile("eureka-client")` to the class. Then when starting up the application you can set a `-Dspring.profiles.active=eureka-client` for the environments other than production.

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableEurekaClient
@Profile("eureka-client")
public class EurekaClientConfiguration {
}
```

Comment: You refreshed my brain! Thanks. Will have a second reading of profiles.

Comment: Can you sepcify this in more detail:  Split out the EnableEurekaClient to another Configuration class and also add an Profile("eureka-client") to the class. I don't know how to do this. Thanks

Comment: added example to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this method as you don't have to create an extra profile:

```
@Configuration
@EnableEurekaClient
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "application.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class EurekaClientConfiguration {
}
```