# How to disable an annotation when running locally?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a Spring Boot API that contains the following ApplicationConfig class:

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
        addCustomMappings(modelMapper);
        return modelMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced // This annotation must be commented out when running on local machine.
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }

}
```

When running locally, I must comment out the @LoadBalanced annotation on the restTemplate method for the API to function properly.  This is not ideal.  I would rather have this annotation automatically disabled based on the environment the app is running in.  I am considering two approaches to solving this problem:

1. I am already using Maven profiles in the pom.  They are named local (default), dev, and prod.  Currently these profiles are being used only to set a config value in the pom.  I wonder if I could specify whether to disable the annotation in question using Maven profiles.
2. I also have different application.yml files being delivered to the project by a config server based on the environment.  Perhaps an environmental variable in the yml will give me the ability to disable the @LoadBalanced annotation.

Either way, I need to figure out how to get the annotation disabled.  How might I go about doing this?  I considered creating two versions of the restTemplate method (one with @LoadBalanced and one without), but I don't know a good way to conditionally call one vs the other.  The method runs on startup due to some Spring magic I do no understand.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried researching Spring boot profiles? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles. I think you can disable non prod annotation based on the profile.

Comment: This looks like it would work.  I’ll give it a try when the workday begins tomorrow.  Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there anyway to disable annotation in spring4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986067/are-there-anyway-to-disable-annotation-in-spring4)